# Streaming audio over HTTP

Tags: audio, stream, soundcloud

Does Soundcloud API has an available stream for a song if given the song title and an artist name?
Will it give an HTTP url to stream that song and a url for that song on Soundcloud? 
Could not find it on Soundcloud published API documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I think that SoundCloud does not support artists-title pairs for the songs.

Problem is that artists (name of users) on SoundCloud are not unique, just the usernames, but to find the artist by username is almost imposible, since there are restrictions in characters for username.

So you can find more users (artists) with the same or similar name, even maybe with the same track title.

The best way is to search the song via the API, find the best match, and than you can get the details of that track.